# fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller, swift4.2

So I want to develop walkthrough screens for my application. 
This is what i have tried so far.

I have 3 View Controllers.

1st View Controller has a UIView and two buttons. UIView is used to display swiping content.
2nd View Controller has two text fields where i want to display some information.(DataViewController)
3rd View Controller is UIPageViewController.

Here is some code for better understanding.

Code for the 1st ViewController.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController{
    let dataSource = ["Heading 1","Heading 2","Heading 3","Heading 4"]
    @IBOutlet weak var welcomeContentView: UIView!
    var currentIndex = 0
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        configureWelcomeSlides()
    }
    func configureWelcomeSlides()
    {
        guard let welcomePageViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: WelcomePageViewController.self)) as? WelcomePageViewController else{
            return
        }
        welcomePageViewController.delegate = self
        welcomePageViewController.dataSource = self

        addChild(welcomePageViewController)
        welcomePageViewController.didMove(toParent: self)
        welcomePageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        welcomeContentView.addSubview(welcomePageViewController.view)

        let views: [String: Any] = ["pageView": welcomePageViewController.view]

        welcomeContentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[pageView]-0-|",
                                                                         options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                                         views: views))
        welcomeContentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[pageView]-0-|",
                                                                         options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0),
                                                                         metrics: nil,
                                                                         views: views))

        guard let startingViewController = detailViewControllerAt(index: currentIndex) else{
            return
        }
        welcomePageViewController.setViewControllers([startingViewController], direction: .forward, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    func detailViewControllerAt(index: Int) -> WelcomePageContentController?{

        if index >= dataSource.count || dataSource.count == 0 {
            return nil
        }

        guard let welcomePageContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: WelcomePageContentController.self)) as? WelcomePageContentController
            else {
            return nil
        }
        welcomePageContentController.index = index
        welcomePageContentController.slideHeading!.text = dataSource[index]
        return welcomePageContentController
    }



}
extension ViewController: UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return currentIndex
    }
    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let welcomePageContentController  = viewController as? WelcomePageContentController

        guard var currentIndex2 = welcomePageContentController?.index else {
            return nil
        }
        currentIndex = currentIndex2

        if currentIndex2 == 0{
            return nil
        }
        currentIndex2 -= 1
        return detailViewControllerAt(index: currentIndex2)
    }
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        let welcomePageContentController  = viewController as? WelcomePageContentController

        guard var currentIndex2 = welcomePageContentController?.index else {
            return nil
        }
        if currentIndex2 == dataSource.count {
            return nil
        }
        currentIndex2 += 1
        currentIndex = currentIndex2
        return detailViewControllerAt(index: currentIndex2)
    }

}
```

Code for the DataViewController (In my case it is named as WelcomePageContentViewController).

```
import UIKit

class WelcomePageContentController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var slideHeading: UITextView?
    @IBOutlet weak var slideText: UITextView?
    var displayText: String!
    var index : Int!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        slideHeading!.text = displayText
        slideText!.text = displayText

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Code for the UIPageViewController (In my case it is named as WelcomePageViewController).

```
import UIKit

class WelcomePageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

I'm accessing textfields from WelcomePageContentController after the viewdidLoad() method but my app is still crashing.

Error Message: fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value.

Crash happens at this line.
        **welcomePageContentController.slideHeading!.text = dataSource[index]** in ViewController class.

Method :-

**func detailViewControllerAt(index: Int) -> WelcomePageContentController?**

Storyboard picture is attached.

Xcode Version (Version 10.1 (10B61))
Swift(4.2)

[image: Storyboard overview]

Comment: The error it self declared that you are returning nil somewhere in code. debug and find it

Comment: its the UITextField which is nill. I have double checked the connections in story board and the connections are valid.

Comment: `fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value UIPageViewController` says pageviewcontroller is nil , right?

Comment: In project navigator, goto `breakpoints` , in left bottom corner `+` add `Exception breakpoint` and run again

Answer (score 1):

When you instantiate a view controller from a storyboard, the view is actually not yet loaded and the `IBOutlet`s are not yet set. It looks like you're trying to forcefully access a `UITextView` that has not been set yet, which results in the crash.

Try adding `welcomePageContentController.loadViewIfNeeded()` right after instantiating the view controller from your storyboard:

```swift
guard let welcomePageContentController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: String(describing: WelcomePageContentController.self)) as? WelcomePageContentController
    else {
    return nil
}

welcomePageContentController.loadViewIfNeeded()

welcomePageContentController.index = index
welcomePageContentController.slideHeading!.text = dataSource[index]
```

This will load the view and populate your `IBOutlet`s with non-nil values (if they are indeed connected to your storyboard), which will allow you to set the text on your text view.

Comment: +1 for the loadViewIfNeeded.
Works like a charm.
Thank you.